# Member Registration Not Always Saving

Tags: members, freemember, registration

We have a registration form using freemember, and it works about 95% of the time.  In rare instances we get the notification email that someone has registered, but it does not save in the database to approve the pending user.  The member just doesn't exist in our system.  I have tested the registration and it works fine for me, I just can't figure out why it would fail in some instances.  Does anyone have any idea about what could cause this issue?  It is strange that it would pass field validation and get to the point of sending the registration notification email but not save.

We are running EE 2.10.3, and I checked the change logs for newer versions and there is no reference to registration issues in the bug fixes.  We are also running the latest version of Freemember.